# locationUpdated is not being called in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, location

im trying to to implement LocationListener and then use locationUpdated, but even after i setup the intervel for it every 10 sec, it seems that locationUpdated is not being called.

```
Criteria myCriteria = new Criteria();
myCriteria.setCostAllowed(false);
LocationProvider provider = LocationProvider.getInstance(myCriteria);

provider.setLocationListener(new LocationHandler(), 10, -1, -1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you first get the provider, it's always a good idea to reset it before setting your location listener:

```
provider.setLocationListener( null, 0, 0, 0 );
provider.reset();
```

Also, if you are using a BrowserField be aware that the field will register its own listener, overriding yours (a known bug). The only workaround for that is to poll the location yourself via getLocation().

Comment: Thats like magic ! i reset the provider and "Everything Went Better Than Expected". thanks .